# Team site missing web & App Part options?

Tags: web-part, team-sites

I've been allowed onto our team SharePoint site as an admin, I've gone to add a Web Part but the options are blank? I've looked into my own team site and they are there?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is a result of one of two things (or a combination of the two).

**FIRST:** You will need to enable Custom scripts for your site/subsite. Microsoft provides steps on how to do this [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/allow-or-prevent-custom-script-1f2c515f-5d7e-448a-9fd7-835da935584f). If this is a site collection other than your root site, you will need to follow the "To allow custom script on other SharePoint site collections" section of this page. ***This process requires access to the tenant admin panel for SharePoint (Office 365 Admin privilege)***

Also note that this will take 24 hours before this setting will take effect. I believe there are ways to have this setting take instantly, but haven't done so myself.

**SECOND:** Depending on which web parts you are looking for, you will need to enable the correct Site Features/ Collection Features. You can do this by:

1. Navigate to the home page for your site.
2. Click the Cog icon at the top of your page
3. Click `Site Settings`
4. From here, depending on the web parts you want to enable, you will find the settings under `Site Collection Administration > Site Collection Features` or `Site Actions > Manage Site Features`. In order to access the Site Collection Administration settings, you will need to be a Site Collections Admin for the site.

It's also worth noting that just following the first piece should add some web parts for you to access and that when enabling features in the second set of steps you need to be careful if you start disabling features.